# Can sklearn in python do nearest neighbour search for points within a ball?

Tags: python

I know sklearn can calculate the k-nearest neighbors of a large data-set well, but it seems like they don't have a function to search for all points within a given radius of a query point.

Is it possible to do such range queries? I am looking for the sklearn analogue to scipy.spatial's KDTree method called [`query_ball_point`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point)

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by retrieving 1, 2, 4, 8, ... nearest neighbors until the radius is exceeded, then discarding the points that are too far from the query point.